# Get an Error when render Tensorflow Camera

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, machine-learning

i have a problem with my code, it is object detection app, when i run it camera loads okay but i get some Promise Errors:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined]

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: When using targetShape.depth=3, targetShape.width must be a multiple of 4. Alternatively do not call detectGLCapabilities()]

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'cast' must be a Tensor or TensorLike, but got 'Tensor']

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Backend 'undefined' has not yet been initialized. Make sure to await tf.ready() or await tf.setBackend() before calling other methods]

this is my code:

```
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import { cameraWithTensors } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";
import * as cocoSsd from "@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd";
import Canvas from "react-native-canvas";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);

function App() {
  const [model, setModel] = useState(null);
  const context = useRef();
  const camera = useRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert("not granted");
        return;
      }
      await tf.ready();
      const loadedModel = await cocoSsd.load();
      setModel(loadedModel);
    })();
  }, []);
  const handleCameraStream = (images) => {
    const loop = async () => {
      const nextImageTensor = images.next().value;

      if (!model || !nextImageTensor) return;

      const predictions = await model.detect(nextImageTensor);

      drawRectangles(predictions);

      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };

    loop();
  };

  const drawRectangles = (predictions) => {
    if (!context.current || !camera.current) return;

    const scaleWidth = width / camera.current.width;
    const scaleHeight = height / camera.current.height;

    context.current.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    for (const prediction of predictions) {
      const [x, y, width, height] = prediction.bbox;

      const boundingBoxX = x * scaleWidth;
      const boundingBoxY = y * scaleHeight;

      context.current.strokeRect(
        boundingBoxX,
        boundingBoxY,
        width * scaleWidth,
        height * scaleHeight
      );

      context.current.fillText(
        `${prediction.class} (${Math.round(prediction.score * 100)}%)`,
        boundingBoxX,
        boundingBoxY > 10 ? boundingBoxY - 5 : 10
      );
    }
  };

  const handleCanvas = (can) => {
    if (can) {
      can.width = width;
      can.height = height;
      const ctx = can.getContext("2d");
      context.current = ctx;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      camera.current = can;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TensorCamera
        style={styles.camera}
        type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
        cameraTextureWidth={width}
        cameraTextureHeight={height}
        resizeWidth={width}
        resizeHeight={height}
        resizeDepth={3}
        onReady={handleCameraStream}
        autorender={true}
        useCustomShadersToResize={false}
      />

      <View style={styles.canvasContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>Detected Objects:</Text>
        <Canvas style={styles.canvas} ref={handleCanvas} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```